# IE/Edge download SharePoint files instead of opening directly for edit

Tags: file, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-edge

I experienced an issue for few days now.
On my laptop, before this issue, I was able to open a sharepoint file directly from IE/Edge by typing the url in the address bar and the document was opened in the good app (Word/Excel/PowerPoint) and let me edit it and save to the SharePoint target.

For days now, I'm not anymore able to edit files, when I type the Url on the address bar, a popup appear with 3 choices: Open, Save and Save as.
If I click on "Open", the document is downloaded on a temp folder and I cannot edit it anymore directly to the SharePoint target.

Nothing has been done on the SharePoint server, I still have the contribute access to documents.
I have already changed the option "Open files in the browser" on edge but nothing changed.
I think something has changed on Registry but I cannot found what.

I already test lot of solutions suggested on forums, but now I'm lost.

Someone else has encountered the same issue ? How did you manage it ?
Thank you

Comment: Does Chrome have the same issue? Maybe you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/files-downloaded-instead-of-opening-office-application), and try the solution in it.

Answer (score -1):

When you open a URL (like http://sharepointserver/Shared%20Documents/DateTest.docx) to a SharePoint document by using the Chromium browser, the document is downloaded directly instead of opening the Office application with a direct connection to the document on SharePoint.

It is how the Chromium browsers work.

To resolve this issue, add "?web=1" to the end of the URL, and then the document will be opened in the Chrome browser.

For example, http://sharepointserver/Shared%20Documents/DateTest.docx?web=1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/files-downloaded-instead-of-opening-office-application